# Apache Tomcat webapp start/deploy time

Tags: tomcat

Is there any way (beside parsing logfiles) to determine when a specific webapp has been started/deployed? Unfortunately the manager does not provide this information and I did not find anything on the web either.

Comment: If it is exploded WAR; deployment time is the time the exploded folder was created in weapps

Comment: Unfortunately this is not true for stopping/starting the webapp:/ I've tested with Apache Tomcat 9.0.84 - you need to fully undeploy/delete the webapp folder.

Comment: Yes, it is only applicable if the WAR is deployed